# StreamWriter automatically flushing buffer when given large messages

Tags: c#, networking, flush, streamwriter

**Overview**

I have a Client-Server whereby I have the `streamWriter.WriteLine(messageToClient);`on the server sending large messages. The `streamReader.ReadLine();` on the client is reading the 2000 length messages fine.

The issue here is the `streamWriter.Flush()` has no affect on the larger messages, because what I am aiming for is the server to be able to switch between the buffers flushing directly (having a fluid server message output) and not (the server response would be jumbled together until it reaches the buffers limit to flush).

**Question:** I am thinking that the buffers are auto flushing because they are full? Is so what is the streamWriters max buffer size?

I have tested using much smaller `messageToClient` and the not flushing of the stream works as intended. Aka the server stream outputs a group of small messages at once to the client, presumably because the buffer was full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [the constructor that takes the buffer size as an argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72d9f8d5.aspx)?

```
public StreamWriter(
    Stream stream,
    Encoding encoding,
    int bufferSize
)
```

**Edit**: poking around in reflector it looks like the default buffer size is 1024 bytes.