# How to turn off StreamWriter.WriteLine() buffer on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use .net core 2.0 on ubuntu.
if i called StreamWriter.WriteLine() on windows,text will save in file immediate.
but on Ubuntu 18.04,it looks buffer some chars.
if i dont call StreamWriter.Dispose().the latest chars will not write in file.about 1500 chars lost.
i will make latest log lost,how to fix it? 
thanks

Comment: have you set `AutoFlush` to `true` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StreamWriter automatically flushing buffer when given large messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670873/streamwriter-automatically-flushing-buffer-when-given-large-messages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't flushed (`Flush()`) the data; you can do that automatically after each append by setting `AutoFlush` to `true`.

Comment: @activesradio If it worked then you should consider accepting the answer as it's fundamental to making SO work since it rewards the person who took the time to answer your question..

Comment: @MarkG i dont know how to accept answer and close this question.thank you again!

Comment: @activesradio See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).